# Redemption not working in my own turn?

Tags: hearthstone

I used Redemption ("Secret: When one of your minions dies, return it to life with 1 Health.") and then attacked an enemy minion, killing my minion. However, this minion was not resurrected.

Redemption then worked in the opposing player's turn.

Is this a bug or a faulty card description? Would it have worked in my next turn?

Comment: I believe secrets only work on your opponent's turn, and are triggered when you are attacked by them ... pending an answer from an actual Hearthstone player :)

Comment: Yeah, that would make sense, gameplay-wise. And I guess it'd bloat the descriptions if the (few) applicable secrets had this information. So maybe it's listed in a rules document somewhere. Or maybe, if it isn't, it could be added in the mouse-over text.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Secrets don't work at all in your own turn, as indicated by the secret indicator greying out when it is your own turn. This was changed in a patch to prevent secrets being used like spells and intentionally triggered by the player that played the secret.

[From the official release notes:](http://us.battle.net/hearthstone/en/blog/13154924/hearthstone-patch-notes-1004944-all-that-glitters-3-11-2014)

> Secrets can now only activate on your opponent’s turn.
>
> Activating your own secrets feels a little strange, but mostly, the
>   ability to do this was preventing us from creating new and powerful
>   secrets that trigger off of events you can easily control (like a
>   minion dying).  They end up functioning just like spells, instead of
>   trying to bait your opponent into a bad play.  This change keeps
>   secrets working like traps you lay for your opponent, instead of
>   spells that you cast and use on your own turn.

Comment: Ooooh, I didn't think about the colour indicator. Thanks for the information. Like I mentioned in a comment to the question, I see the point gameplay-wise in not letting the caster trigger their secrets. But it seemed a bit ill-communicated to me. But perhaps I should just pay more attention to visual cues.

Comment: @ChristoferOlsson I think it's mentioned in the game's tutorial. However it was a feature that was recently changed, so some users may have missed the patch notes.

Comment: @Michael: No. The tutorial is limited to basic gameplay, using only Free and tutorial-specific cards. None of the secrets fall in either category.

Comment: I understand why it was changed, because some secrets were just too powerful to trigger intentionally. I do kind of miss the "Misdirection unto Misdirection" combo though, that was always good fun.